# Pass user id via props in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React. I have **App.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import About from './components/About';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Form from './components/forms/Form';
import Logout from './components/Logout';
import UserStatus from './components/UserStatus';
import Seeds from './components/Seeds';
import Message from './components/Message';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      title: 'Project',
      isAuthenticated: false,
      messageName: null,
      messageType: null,   
    };
    this.logoutUser = this.logoutUser.bind(this);
    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
    this.createMessage = this.createMessage.bind(this);
    this.removeMessage = this.removeMessage.bind(this);
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
    };
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  };
  getUsers() {
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/users`)
    .then((res) => { this.setState({ users: res.data.data.users }); })
    .catch((err) => { });
  };
  logoutUser() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false });
  };
  loginUser(token) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
    this.getUsers();
    this.createMessage('Welcome', 'success');
  };
  createMessage(name='Sanity Check', type='success') {
    this.setState({
      messageName: name,
      messageType: type
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.removeMessage();
    }, 3000);
  };
  removeMessage() {
    this.setState({
      messageName: null,
      messageType: null
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar
          title={this.state.title}
          isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
        />
        <section className="section">
          <div className="container">
            {this.state.messageName && this.state.messageType &&
              <Message
                messageName={this.state.messageName}
                messageType={this.state.messageType}
                removeMessage={this.removeMessage} 
              />
            }
            <div className="columns">
              <div className="column is-half">
                <br/>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
                    <SpotifyAuth
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
                  <Route exact path='/register' render={() => (
                    <Form
                      formType={'Register'}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      loginUser={this.loginUser}
                      createMessage={this.createMessage} 
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/login' render={() => (
                    <Form
                      formType={'Login'}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      loginUser={this.loginUser}
                      createMessage={this.createMessage} 
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/logout' render={() => (
                    <Logout
                      logoutUser={this.logoutUser}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/status' render={() => (
                    <UserStatus
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/seeds' render={() => (
                    <Seeds
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    />
                  )} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

this **Form.jsx** component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { registerFormRules, loginFormRules, spotifyLoginFormRules } from './form-rules.js';
import FormErrors from './FormErrors.jsx';


class Form extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formData: {
        restaurant: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      registerFormRules: registerFormRules,
      loginFormRules: loginFormRules,
      valid: false,
    };
    this.handleUserFormSubmit = this.handleUserFormSubmit.bind(this);

  componentDidMount() {
    this.clearForm();
  };
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.formType !== nextProps.formType) {
      this.clearForm();
    };
  };
  clearForm() {
    this.setState({
      formData: {restaurant: '', username: '', email: '', password: ''}
    });
  };
  handleFormChange(event) {
    const obj = this.state.formData;
    obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
    this.validateForm(); 
  };
  handleUserFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formType = this.props.formType
    const data = {
      restaurant: this.state.formData.restaurant,
      email: this.state.formData.email,
      password: this.state.formData.password
    };
    if (formType === 'Register') {
      data.username = this.state.formData.username
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/auth/${formType.toLowerCase()}`;
    axios.post(url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        this.clearForm();
        this.props.loginUser(res.data.auth_token);
    })
    .catch((err) => {

      if (formType === 'Login') {
        this.props.createMessage('Login failed.', 'danger');
      };

      if (formType === 'Register') {
        this.props.createMessage('That user already exists.', 'danger');
      };
    });
  };
  allTrue() {
    let formRules = loginFormRules;
    if (this.props.formType === 'Register') {
      formRules = registerFormRules;
    }
    for (const rule of formRules) {
      if (!rule.valid) return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  resetRules() {
    const registerFormRules = this.state.registerFormRules;
    for (const rule of registerFormRules) {
      rule.valid = false;
    }
    this.setState({registerFormRules: registerFormRules})

    const loginFormRules = this.state.loginFormRules;
    for (const rule of loginFormRules) {
      rule.valid = false;
    }
    this.setState({loginFormRules: loginFormRules})
  };
  validateEmail(email) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  };
  render() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/' />);
    };
    let formRules = this.state.loginFormRules;  
    if (this.props.formType === 'Register') {
      formRules = this.state.registerFormRules;
    }
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.formType === 'Login' &&
        <h1 className="title is-1">Log In</h1>
      }
      {this.props.formType === 'Register' &&
        <h1 className="title is-1">Register</h1>
      }
      <hr/><br/>
      <FormErrors
        formType={this.props.formType}
        formRules={formRules}
      />
      <form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleUserFormSubmit(event)}>
       {this.props.formType === 'Register' &&
        <div className="field">
         <input
          name="restaurant"
          className="input is-medium"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your restaurant name"
          required
          value={this.state.formData.coffeeshop}
          onChange={this.handleFormChange}
        /> 
        </div>
        }
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="username"
              className="input is-medium"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter a username"
              required
              value={this.state.formData.username}
              onChange={this.handleFormChange}
            />
          </div>
        <div className="field">
          <input
            name="email"
            className="input is-medium"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter an email address"
            required
            value={this.state.formData.email}
            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <input
            name="password"
            className="input is-medium"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter a password"
            required
            value={this.state.formData.password}
            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
          />
        </div>
        <input
          type="submit"
          className="button is-primary is-medium is-fullwidth"
          value="Submit"
          disabled={!this.state.valid}  
        />
      </form>
    </div>
    )
  };
};

export default Form;
```

and **UserStatus.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import './css/box.css'


class UserStatus extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      restaurant:'',      
      email: '',
      id: '',
      username: '',
      active: '',
      admin: ''    
    };
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getUserStatus();
    }
  };
  getUserStatus(event) {
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => { 
      console.log(res.data)  
      console.log(res.data.data) 
      this.setState({
        restaurant: res.data.data.restaurant,
        email: res.data.data.email,
        id: res.data.data.id,
        username: res.data.data.username,
        active: String(res.data.data.active),
        admin: String(res.data.data.admin),
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
  render() {
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (
        <p>You must be logged in to view this. Click <Link to="/login">here</Link> to log back in.</p>
      )
    };
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">Current User</font></h1>
      <hr/><br/>
      <ul>
        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">restaurant:</font></strong><font color="white"> {this.state.restaurant} </font></li>
        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">User ID:</font></strong><font color="white"> {this.state.id} </font></li>
        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">Email:</font></strong><font color="white"> {this.state.email} </font></li>
        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">Username:</font></strong><font color="white"> {this.state.username} </font></li>
        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">Active:</font></strong><font color="white"> {this.state.active} </font></li>
        <li><strong><font color="#C86428">Admin:</font></strong><font color="white"> {this.state.admin} </font></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
  };
};

export default UserStatus;
```

finally, this Seeds.jsx, where I need `user.id` in order to call my backend, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class Seeds extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        restaurant:'',      
        email: '',
        id: '',
        username: '',
        active: '',
        admin: '',
        template:'',
      formSeeds:{
        type1:'',
        type2:'',
        type3:'',
      },
      formEditMenu:{
        item:'',
        item2:'',
        item3:'',
      }
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitSeeds = this.handleSubmitSeeds.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitCoffees = this.handleSubmitCoffees.bind(this);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getSeeds();
    }
  };
  getSeeds(event) {
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/seeds/${this.props.getUserStatus.id}`, //HERE
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.data)
      this.setState({
        restaurant: res.data.data[0].restaurant,
        id: res.data.data[0].id,
        template: res.data.data[0].content
      })
      console.log(res.data.data[0].id);
    })    
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
  handleChange(event){
    const objformSeeds = this.state.formSeeds;
    objformSeeds[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(objformSeeds);

    const formEditMenu = this.state.formEditMenu;
    formEditMenu[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(formEditMenu);
    }
  handleSubmitSeeds(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //const formSeeds = this.props.formSeeds
    const data = {
      type1: this.state.formSeeds.type1,
      type2: this.state.formSeeds.type2,
      type3: this.state.formSeeds.type3,
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/handle_seeds`;
    axios.post(url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  };
  handleSubmitCoffees(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //const formEditMenu = this.props.formEditMenu
    const data = {
      item:  this.state.formEditMenu.item,
      item2: this.state.formEditMenu.item2,
      item3: this.state.formEditMenu.item3,
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/edit_menu${this.props.getUserStatus.id}`; //AND HERE
    axios.post(url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
    };

    render(){

        //var seeds_page = this.state.template;
        var __html = this.state.template;
        var template = { __html: __html };

        return (
           <div id="parent">
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template}/>
              <form>
                <input type='text' name='name' onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmitCoffees} />
              </form>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Seeds;
```

I am trying to get id via `props` (`this.props.getUserStatus.id`), but I get `undefined`. How do I pass my user.id to Seeds.jsx component here?

Comment: You aren't passing a `getUserStatus` prop to `<Seeds />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you may want to use a store like redux for state management. If you really want to keep your state locally, then you should "lift it", and move your getUserStatus() function in the highest possible parent (in your case App.js). In your App.js you then set a userStatus object in the state and pass it down to all components which need it.

```
<Route exact path='/seed' render={() => (
   <Seed
     ....
     userStatus={this.state.userStatus} 
   />
)} />
```

and in your child component:

```
....
render(){
  const { userStatus } = this.props
  return(
    ......
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/edit_menu${userStatus.id}`;


  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only property you passed to Seeds is `isAuthenticated`.

Comment: Where do I pass it then?

Comment: <Seeds prop1={whatever} prop2={whatever} prop3={whatever}/>  That's how you pass properties.

Comment: I see. I admire your brevity, but your comment it too generic. and I used very specific code above. could you provide a specific solution, please?